# C++ interface without virtual functions

Tags: c++, interface, static-polymorphism

I was wondering how we can declare an interface in C++ without using virtual functions. After some internet searching I put together this solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

// Definition of a type trait to check if a class defines a member function "bool foo(bool)"
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_foo : false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_foo<T, typename enable_if<is_same<bool, decltype(std::declval<T>().foo(bool()))>::value, void>::type> : true_type { };

// Definition of a type trait to check if a class defines a member function "void bar()"    
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_bar : false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_bar<T, typename enable_if<is_same<void, decltype(std::declval<T>().bar())>::value, void>::type> : true_type { };

// Class defining the interface
template <typename T>
class Interface{
public:
  Interface(){
    static_assert(has_foo<T>::value == true, "member function foo not implemented");
    static_assert(has_bar<T>::value == true, "member function bar not implemented");
  }
};

// Interface implementation
class Implementation:Interface<Implementation>{
public:
  // If the following member functions are not declared a compilation error is returned by the compiler
  bool foo(bool in){return !in;}
  void bar(){}
};

int main(){}
```

I'm planning to use this design strategy in a project where I will use static polymorphism only.
The C++ standard I will use in the project is C++11.

What do you think are the pros and cons of this approach?

What improvements can be made on the code I proposed?

**EDIT 1:**
I just realised that inheriting from Interface is not needed. This code could also be used:

```
class Implementation{
  Interface<Implementation> unused;
public:
  bool foo(bool in){return !in;}
  void bar(){}
};
```

**EDIT 2-3:**
One major difference between the static_assert solution (with or without CRTP) and the standard CRTP is that the CRTP does not guarantee that the derived class implements all the interface members. E.g., the following code compiles correctly:

```
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template< typename T>
class Interface{
public:
  bool foo(bool in){
    return static_cast<T*>(this)->foo(in);
  }
  void bar(){
    static_cast<T*>(this)->bar();
  }
};

class Implementation: public Interface<Implementation>{
public:
//    bool foo(bool in){return !in;}
//    void bar(){}
};

int main(){}
```

An error about a missing member function will be returned by the compiler only when the functions *foo* or *bar* will be required.

The way I see it, the static_assert solution feels more like an interface declaration than CRTP alone.

Comment: Have you looked at [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: @Amadeus Yes, a long time ago but unfortunately I had forgotten about it...

Comment: `class Implementation:Interface<Implementation>`. This is CRTP and nothing else. CRTP is this and nothing else. `static_assert`s are optional, they only provide nicer error messages.

Comment: @n.m. : you are right, but as I wrote in **EDIT 1** there is no need of using CRTP. I will update my question

Comment: Note that the problem mentioned in EDIT 2 can be circumvented by calling  `bar_impl` rather than `bar` ie `void bar(){
    static_cast<T*>(this)->bar_impl();
  }` then the compiler will complain at compile time if `bar_impl` doesn't exist (rather than stackoverflowing by recursively calling the wrong `bar`...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you want to implement [concepts (lite)](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s). You may want to read the article before attempting an implementation.

Absent compiler support, you can partially implement this idea. Your `static_assert` idea is a known way to express interface requirements.

Consider the `Sortable` example from the link. You can create a class template `Sortable`, use `static_assert` to assert all kind of thinks about the template parameter. You explain to your users that they need to implement a certain cet of methods, and to enforce that set is implemented, they need to make use of `Sortable<TheirClass>` one way or another.

In order to express, right in a function declaration. the idea that your function requires a `Sortable`, you will have to resort to something like this:

```
template <typename Container> 
auto doSomethingWithSortable (Container&) -> std::enable_if<Implements<Container, Sortable>>::type;
```

Answer (score 7):

An common way to implement static polymorphism is to use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

With this pattern, you define an templated interface class, whose methods forward to the template:

```
// Interface
template <typename T>
struct base {
    void foo(int arg) {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->do_foo(arg);
    }
};
```

You implementation the inherits from the base class and implements the methods:

```
// Implementation
struct derived : base<derived> {
    void do_foo(int arg) {
        std::cout << arg << '\n'
    } 
};
```

This pattern has the advantage that it looks "feels" a lot like regular runtime polymorphism, and the error messages are generally quite sane. Because all the code is visible to the compiler, everything can be inlined so there's no overhead.

Comment: I came across CRTP a long time ago but completely forgotten about it... I edited my question to add a possible advantage of using the method I proposed.

Comment: maybe I was not clear enough in my original question. What I'm looking for is a way to declare an interface. Playing with CRTP I discovered that there is an important difference with the proposed solution. Please see **EDIT 2** in my question.

Comment: Don't forget to declare virtual destructor if you are going to delete Implementation via pointer to interface